# How to update the yaml root key in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

I have a requirement to compare the yaml files to identify the differences in it and for that i need yaml files to start with same root key. Is it possible to update the yaml root key in ruby? (Note: Not the value in the yml file)

Yaml file example:

```
person:
  name: abc
  age: 10
  address: xyz
```

My requirement is to update the yaml file as below.

```
student:
  name: abc
  age: 10
  address: xyz
```

Thanks in advance for help!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not 100% sure what you are looking for but once you load the yaml, you end up with a ruby hash.  You can then just create a new hash with a new name for the root key.

For example this:

```rb
require 'yaml'

input = 
"person:
  name: abc
  age: 10
  address: xyz"

obj = YAML.load(input)
new_obj = {"student" => obj["person"]}
output = YAML.dump(new_obj)
puts output
```

will print:

```
---
student:
  name: abc
  age: 10
  address: xyz
```

If for whatever reason you don't want the doc header "---" you can remove it with.

```
no_header = output.split("\n").drop(1).join("\n")
puts no_header
```

Which will print:

```
student:
  name: abc
  age: 10
  address: xyz
```

Comment: Thanks you, It served my purpose.
`new_obj = {"student" => YAML.load_file('path')['person']}
output = YAML.dump(new_obj)
puts output`